# Download Webpage C# missing content

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I try to downloaded a web page using the DownloadString() method (C#).
When I open the string as HTML i can see the details that i looking for
but when i try to search in the text as text document for the content it doesn't exist.
Example:
Link: https://www.truecaller.com/search/il/0535284243
Trying to find in html text: Anonymous 14

How can I solve this problem or is there another way to get user info from truecaller in C# programatically?

Comment: Some parts of the page may appear after ajax requests. Try to check how page is loading in `Fiddler`

Comment: Can you explain more please? i'm kind of new in web testing  @opewix

Comment: Please show the code you have, so we can see what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

try work around by using this page https://www.phphive.info/324/truecaller-api/

if you used the work of this developer you can get the data using his url as described, or directly by downloading the page using his of his url:

https://tcapi.phphive.info/"+apiToken+"/search/"+ [put phone number here]

but it may have limitations

Comment: I found the solution by using Selenium, check below video and the series around it and you will figure out how solve this ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7I0LXQ-nHVc